# Does a 7 years old child need a separate bank statement?

Tags: schengen, children, schengen-visas

I am going to apply for a Schengen tourist visa from the French embassy. My 7 years  old daughter is accompanying  me and I have a good bank statement. she is in the second class in school.

Does she need to have a separate bank statement?
What other documents does she need to complete the visa requirement? her visa application has been rejected twice.

Comment: No, there is no reason for a 7 y.o. applying as an accompanying dependent to include a bank statement.  As for other documents she would include something naming you as the bio father. If there are any Hague implications, she should include those documents also.

Comment: I've answered your question about her bank statements. We generally don't allow two questions in one question unless they are very closely related, which these seem not. Feel free to ask why her visa got rejected and what you can do about it in a new question. Do add her refusal letter with her personal details removed to the question.

Comment: *her visa application has been rejected twice* It helps to tell us why (what was missing?)

Comment: Are both parents traveling? If not, you might want to include a notarized statement from the non-traveling parent that they agree to the trip.

Answer (score 1):

You should submit the bank statements of the person paying for her trip. If that is you, then no, she does not need a separate bank statement. If that is herself (which seems unlikely), then submit her own bank statement. If that is someone else (other parent, grandparent) then you should submit their bank statement.

See [this answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/66105/36405) on what bank statements should show.